# How to do integration testing on an API wrapper

Tags: java, integration-testing, wiremock

I have an api wrapper that is just your basic controller/service that is using a third party client to actually handle requests. Is it possible to mock this for integration testing somehow?

```
Clientservice clientService = new ClientService(urlHere);
clientService.findBooks(); //Handles request within, my wrapper does not directly call endpoints
```

What's the proper way to integrate test this? Just call my controller with rest and mock the clientService return? Unsure if it's possible to do this another way.

Edit: changed title and info to try and make this clearer.

Comment: You want to mock Clientservice, did I get it right? In that case mock it with Mockito.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so.. I'm new to testing and trying to discern how to possibly do proper integration testing with this API wrapper. 
I just have a controller mapped to requests and the controller essentially just calls the clientService.

Answer (score 0):

You mock a api service within smart bears Soapui tool:

https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html